# Filtering a Pivot Table based on text string in a cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("K2:K3")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim Field As Variant
    Dim NewCat As String
    Set pt = Worksheets("Fact Trans").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
    Set Field = pt.PivotFields("[Locations].[Loc Name].[Location Name]")
    NewCat = Worksheets("Fact Trans").Range("K2").Value
    With pt
        Field.ClearAllFilters
        Field.CurrentPage = NewCat
        pt.RefreshTable
    End With

End Sub
```

So as you can see I'm trying to change my pivot table based on the value in K2, but I keep getting the error "Run-time error '1004': Unable to set CurrentPage property of the PivotField class"  and debug highlight's line "Field.CurrentPage = NewCat"  .

Any insight on why and how I can get this code to work will be great.

Comment: Typically when you use a `With` block, you need a leading `.` in front of the objects that are part of that parent object.

Comment: What do you mean chrismas007?

Comment: Check out [This Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) at the examples.

Comment: Now I get Run-Time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method, I'm lost lol @Chrismas007

Comment: To be honest, after looking at your code, I don't think you even need the `With` or `End With` lines...

Comment: Yeah but that automates my VBA, without it the pivottable won't react  to the cell value @Chrismas007

Comment: See this link: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=169855 My guess is that the field is not a Page Field.

Comment: Thanks the linked worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the updated code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)


If Intersect(Target, Range("K2:K3")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Dim pt As PivotTable

Dim Field As Variant

Dim NewCat As String


Set pt = Worksheets("Fact Trans").PivotTables("PivotTable1")

Set Field = pt.PivotFields("[Locations].[Loc Name].[Location Name]")

NewCat = Worksheets("Fact Trans").Range("K2").Value


With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("[Locations].[Loc Name].[Location Name]")
    .ClearAllFilters

.PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionEquals, Value1:=ActiveSheet.Range("K3").Value

End With

End Sub
```